# Under what circumstances can a single consumer process consume multiple partitions simultaneously?

Tags: hadoop, apache-kafka, flume

## env

- kafka 1.0.1
- flume 1.9.0

## trouble

Using Kafka Channel, I am loading data to Hadoop with flume sink.

The flume properties are:

```
topicLoader.sinks.k9.hdfs.rollInterval = 180
topicLoader.sinks.k9.hdfs.rollSize = 754974720
topicLoader.sinks.k9.hdfs.rollCount = 0
topicLoader.sinks.k9.hdfs.callTimeout = 100000
topicLoader.sinks.k9.hdfs.round = True
topicLoader.sinks.k9.hdfs.roundValue = 60
topicLoader.sinks.k9.hdfs.roundUnit = minute
topicLoader.sinks.k9.hdfs.batchSize = 2000
```

The number of partitions for the topic i'm currently using is 150.
The number of flume channel threads and the number of sink threads is set to 150 according to the number of partitions.

However, one consumer process is consuming multiple partitions.
So, only that partition increases lag a lot.

I set the number of partitions and the number of processes to be the same, but I'm curious as to why this happens.

Comment: what is your consumer count? consumer thread count?

Comment: yes i mean thread count